# how to insert an array of id's into linq-to-sql query line in .net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

i want to get an array of id's which is like `["15", "26", "37", "48", "90"]` and i want to get my remaining items from my remaining table that doesnt includes these supplier id's..

here what i done so far:

```
string[] arrgroupdetails;
arrgroupdetails = dataContext.GroupDetails.Select(c => c.supplier_id).ToArray();

var items = from thingies in dataContext.remainings where thingies.supplier_id.ToString() != arrgroupdetails.Any().ToString() select thingies;
```

so how can i achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By heart, so do check syntax but someething like this should work:

```
var items = from thingies in dataContext.remainings 
where !arrgroupdetails.Contains(thingies.supplier_id.ToString())
select thingies;
```

Comment: what if the name of supplier_id is different in other table? if its like `sup_id` in the other table what should i do then?

i mean if its like

`arrgroupdetails = dataContext.GroupDetails.Select(c => c.sup_id).ToArray();` 

and 

`from thingies in dataContext.remainings 
where thingies.supplier_id`

Comment: the name does not matter, you just compare strings in the array to the string in the table